# Limit the number of onChange triggers

Tags: reactjs, redux, tsx

I have this component with a `textarea` where I set the `value` to `{store.some_property}` from the Redux store. My intention is to update the store by dispatching an action using the `onChange` event on the `textarea`. However, the issue is that using `onChange` triggers an action each time a key is pressed. I'm looking for a way to limit the number of these triggers. I believe the problem is a general one and doesn't necessarily require the code. Nevertheless, here's my component, and there is only one `textarea` in it, so if you need a reference, here it is:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab'
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { RootState } from '../store/reducers/store'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import * as documentActions from '../store/actions/documents'
import * as translationActions from '../store/actions/translations'
import TranslationLine from '../components/translation/TranslationLine'
const organizeText = (inputText: string) => {
    // Step 1: Combine all lines together
    let combinedText = inputText.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()

    // Step 2: Remove dashes and combine the words around the dash
    combinedText = combinedText.replace(/‐ /g, '')

    // Step 3: Separate the lines using dots
    const lines = combinedText.split('.').map((line) => line.trim())
    const processedText = lines.join('.\n')

    return processedText
}

const Translation = () => {
    const params = useParams()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const pageID: string = params.page || ''
    const page = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.documents.curDocument.pages[pageID])
    const translations = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.translations)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!page) {
            dispatch(documentActions.getPageDetails(pageID))
        }
        if (page?.best_transcription) {
            dispatch(translationActions.setDefaultTranslationText(page))
        }
    }, [dispatch, page, pageID])

    const handleOrganizeButton = () => {
        const organizedText = organizeText(translations.copticTextForTranslation)
        dispatch(translationActions.setOrganizedTranslationText(organizedText))
    }
    const handleResetButton = () => {
        dispatch(translationActions.setDefaultTranslationText(page))
    }
    const handleTextChange = () => {
        const textarea = document.getElementById('copticTextarea') as HTMLTextAreaElement
        const textareaValue = textarea.value
        dispatch(translationActions.setOrganizedTranslationText(textareaValue))
    }
    return (
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey="organizeText" id="uncontrolled-tab-example" className="mb-3">
            <Tab eventKey="organizeText" title="Text organization">
                {translations && (
                    <>
                        <div className="container">
                            <textarea
                                id={'copticTextarea'}
                                className="form-control fs-4"
                                rows={8}
                                value={translations.copticTextForTranslation}
                                onChange={() => handleTextChange()}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
                            <button className="btn btn-success me-3" onClick={() => handleOrganizeButton()}>
                                Organize text
                            </button>
                            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => handleResetButton()}>
                                Reset text
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )}
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="translation" title="Translation">
                <div className="container">
                    {translations.copticTextForTranslation.split('\n').map((line, index) => (
                        <TranslationLine key={index} originalText={line} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    )
}

export default Translation
```

Comment: It is generally not recommended to do that. There is the technique of debouncing, where you wait for keypresses to have stopped for a while until you dispatch an action (see lodash debounce for example). This reduces the number and frequency of actions dispatched. But ultimately you don't want to have the value of the textarea be sourced straight from the redux state. I'd use a local state var in this component to keep the content of the textarea. Then you can add a `useEffect` where the value is propagated to from local state to redux. This inner function of the effect can be debounced.

Comment: The result of a state, alongside a useEffect to trigger whenever the state is changed, is completely the same as this, with extra more steps, or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: the difference is that the onChange handler can fire as often as necessary for every keypress, the users sees the characters they're typing right away, but you're not sending every update through the entire redux machinery. Official redux docs are even advising against that, as it "causes performance overhead and provides no real benefit" source: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux

Comment: The basic gist is that you should throttle or debounce whatever function you are using that is "expensive" or "heavy". Dispatching actions to update a string in state shouldn't be a heavy lift at all though. Are you having some performance issue or bottleneck somewhere in your code? Is `translationActions.setOrganizedTranslationText` an asynchronous action and you want to rate-limit *that* logic? Please [edit] to clarify what the actual problem is that you are trying to solve that you think limiting the `onChange` event will fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a technique called "debounce". Check [Lodash Debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) for implementing a debounced function. A debounced function is only executed after certain time interval has elapsed since the last time it was invoked. However, since you're using redux state as value for the textarea, users will see the updated value in textarea element only after they've stopped typing and debounced function is executed. You could make the textarea an uncontrolled element.

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const handleTextChange = (e) => {
    const textareaValue = e.target.value
    dispatch(translationActions.setOrganizedTranslationText(textareaValue))
}

const debouncedHandleTextChange = debounce(handleTextChange, 500);
```

Uncontrolled Textarea element:

```
<div className="container">
    <textarea
       id={'copticTextarea'}
       className="form-control fs-4"
       rows={8}
       onChange={debouncedHandleTextChange}
       defaultValue={translations.copticTextForTranslation}
     />
</div>
```

Checkout this demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/compassionate-gagarin-6ymhwh) for reference.

Comment: This does not work. As using debounce here alongside with the `value` property, does not let you to change the text.

Comment: @Vahid Yeah. You have to use uncontrolled textarea element (without value property) as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But I do need it to have an initial value.

Comment: @Vahid You can use defaultValue property and pass the redux state as it's value. I've updated my answer with a demo link.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the problem with defaultValue is that, then after changing the text, you can not reset it to the initial value. Still, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Diwakar There's no need to use `document.getElementById` in a React app. Also you forgot the `value` prop on the textarea.

Comment: @Vahid I don't think you can reset the textarea value to initial state either way until the Translation component is unmounted because the translations.copticTextForTranslation will already be changed after user start typing, whether you're using uncontrolled or controlled textarea element or am I missing something?

Comment: @timotgl Yes. I just used OPs existing solution. In my demo, I've used event.target.value. I guess I should've changed it here also. Also, I did not use value prop because the textarea element is supposed to be uncontrolled one for OPs requirement.

Comment: @Diwakar I didn't see that OP already used it, my bad.